# check user inserted string is valid HTML or not

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I have one `textarea` for user to insert html using `tinymce`.
And i am using `html2pdf` library to print that content in `PDF`.
But, sometime user inserts invalid html like this,

```
<p><span>test</p>
```

So it cause the error while printing PDF.

So what i want is to check before printing that if HTML is valid or not like this,

```
if(valid_html)
   PRINT_PDF
else
   strip_tags(PRINT_PDF); // removing tags from sting
```

For that i tried this solution also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167074/which-function-in-php-validate-if-the-string-is-valid-html).
But not working in many cases. I need solution for this to allow users to print pdf.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html  it may useful

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML to ensure that it is valid is not an easy task in any language - I draw your attention to two particular articles here on stackoverflow, namely this ["How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) and also ["RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

That said, I have found that you can do some rudimentary parsing using `DOMDocument` but it is far from perfect - it might however be sufficient for your purposes.

```
<?php
        $textarea_contents=$_POST['name_of_textarea'];

        $buffer = urldecode( $textarea_contents );
        $errors = array();
        $status=200;

        $dom=new DOMDocument();
        $dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
        libxml_use_internal_errors( TRUE );
        $dom->loadHTML( $buffer );
        $results=libxml_get_errors();
        $dom=NULL;
        libxml_clear_errors();

        if( !empty( $results ) && count( $results ) > 0 ){
            /* Errors detected, prevent further processing of your pdf */
            $status=400;
            foreach( $results as $error ){
                $errors[]=array(
                    'message'   =>  $error->message,
                    'code'      =>  $error->code,
                    'line'      =>  $error->line,
                    'level'     =>  $error->level,
                    'column'    =>  $error->column
                );
            }
        } else {
            /* Hopefully the submitted data validated OK - create PDF */
        }
?>
```

Comment: in your code, i am submitting this data `<p><strong>Set Up</strong><br> Set up a row of cones 5-10 m apart.<br> <strong>Instructions</strong><br>First player.<br> <strong>Points</strong></p> <ul> <li>tap</li> <li>Relax body</li> <li>surfaces (inside foot, thigh.`         but not validating proper. even this is invalid html it goes in else` condition.