# Identify the (weat)her using regexr tool

Tags: php, regex

I am using this tool  http://regexr.com/3fvg9 
I want to mark this (weat)her in regexxr tool.

```
       (weath)er is good.   // i want to mark this word
       (weather is go)od.   // i want to mark this word
```

Please help me.

Comment: Your comments say "known" word. However, a regex does not know if a word is known or not, it just matches a sequence of specific characters. I guess you do not want to match `Weather(is fine)`, right? Otherwise, [something like this would be useful](http://regexr.com/3fvgc).

Comment: yes, i  does not want to  match this words. Weather(is fine),(Weather) is good.

Comment: Then you cannot use regex. Use some spelling dictionary to check matched words against to either accept or ignore the match with the regex like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/1) (analyze Group 1 and 2 contents).

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew thanks this is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to check with a regex if a word is "known" or not, I suggest extracting these parts you need first and then use a kind of a spelling dictionary to check if the words are correct. It won't be 100% accurate, but still better than pure regex.

The expression you need to extract the parts of glued words with parentheses is

```
(?|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)|\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)([a-zA-Z0-9]+))
```

See the [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/1) that supports PHP regex.

The regex matches 2 alternatives inside a branch reset group inside which all capturing groups in different branches are numbered starting with the same ID:

- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)` - Group 1 (`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`) matching 1+ alphanumeric chars, then `(`, and then Group 2 (`([a-zA-Z\s]+)`) matching 1+ letters and whitespaces and then a `)` is matched
- `|` - or
- `\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`  - a `(`, then Group 1 (`([a-zA-Z\s]+)`) matching 1+ letters and whitespaces, `)`, and then Group 2 (`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`) matching 1+ alphanumeric chars

Comment: Please help this pattern. example here
 https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/8

Comment: Pleas also guide this one. I want to handle single brackets {,(,[

https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/13

Comment: @RaheelAslam: Please check https://regex101.com/r/lJrbGy/1. However, I am unsure now what you want to really match. Please narrow it down and explain what exactly you want to match in each case. and yes, it is a new question already.

Comment: i just want that what if user start with `(` but he/she didn't close, then i want to highlight it example: " (wheater "

Comment: See [PHP regexp - Detect unclosed brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575257/php-regexp-detect-unclosed-brackets).

Comment: i have understand this, but still problem here, I want to mark sentence if with start the single bracket and not ending bracket. when i match with single bracket it's matches with double brackets using regex
Example
1- we(ather is fine    / it should be mark
2- (weather is fine)  / it should  not be mark
3- wea{ther             / it  should be mark
4- {weather}           / it should not be mark.
same case for other brackets
updated link
https://regex101.com/r/lJrbGy/5

Comment: Please add these details to your new question, I cannot help with this one since I find it unclear/too broad.